# Asking if a Bernoulli matrix and its variants satisfy the Restricted Isoperimetric Property (RIP) condition

Tags: probability, matrices, optimization, signal-processing, random-matrices

This is regarding the [compressed sensing](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/compressedSensing.pdf) problem that I recently learned about. In the problem $y=X\beta$ where $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$, it is known that a random matrix $X$ where $X\sim_{\text{iid}}N(0,1/n)$ satisfy the Restricted Isoperimetric Property (RIP) condition with high probability.

My questions:

- Is it true that if $X_{ij}\sim_{\text{iid}}\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a fixed constant in $(0,1)$, then $X$ still satisfies RIP with high probability? This [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904519300437?casa_token=tKf8tIVfwVEAAAAA:xn0LmZG7cJOw7kgLZ-Ba7dB8_ghjT0AGhPnbFe_N2JmiOfNw9OtmkJydgNVnQKKMThvDnc-tl9lA) looked at symmetric Bernoulli matrices where entries are in $\{-1,+1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$ which is what I am looking at.
- We have a matrix constructed from a diagonal of matrices:
  $$
  X=\text{diag}(A,\dots,A)
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  A & \dots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & \dots & A
  \end{bmatrix},
  $$
  where $A\in\{0,1\}^{L\times L}$ and entries of $A$ are from $\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha)$ with fixed constant $\alpha$ in $(0,1)$. The scaling of $L$ is $L\in\Theta(p)$, $n/p=\Theta(1)$, $L<n,p$. Does $X$ still satisfy the RIP condition with high probability?

Thanks.